# Hidden post input, or get variable?

Tags: design-patterns

Let's say you're making a blog application, and you're trying to decide how to build the comment form for a particular post. Would you

1. put the `blog_post_id` as a hidden form field in the comment form, or would you
2. set the form action to `post_comment?blog_post_id=<id>` and then grab it from the `GET` variable instead?

Why?

---

My 2 cents:

If you put it into POST, then all your variables are in a consistent location when you're trying to process the form. However, I find that often the `blog_post_id` will be in the URL anyway, so you're sending a tiny bit of extra unneeded data (and have to go through the work of printing the hidden field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically there really isn't a whole lot of difference between the two options. Personally, I'd go with the hidden `POST` because the URL looks cleaner and you won't have to worry about URL escaping the value`*`.

`*` That should be a non-issue for a numeric id, but oh well...

---

Re Edit:

> However, I find that often the `blog_post_id` will be in the URL anyway...

This is totally up to you. If you want it there, you can put it there, but you don't need to.

> ...and have to go through the work of printing the hidden field.

Again, there really isn't a whole lot of difference...

```
<form action="/post_comment?post_id=<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

vs.

```
<form action="/post_comment">
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
```

The hidden input provides a better separation of concerns (on a micro-scale) and is IMHO slightly more readable, while the `GET` variable is one line less code... Take your pick. :)

Comment: Except most of the time it'll be appearing in the URL anyway, because you typically want to redirect back to that blog post so you can see your comment.

Comment: @Mark Redirecting back to the post doesn't mean you have to put anything in the URL to `/post_comment`.

Comment: Well...no, not necessarily. I guess you could stuff that into post too?? But when you want to *view* a page, it typically makes sense to have it in the URL, no?

Comment: @Marc Well, yes, for *viewing* a page (GET requests) you'll need some parameter in the URL, unless you want to turn RESTfulness on its head and make every page a POST page. As concerns your question though, I'd prefer to use a URL as clean as possible. You asked for opinions, that's mine. You can debate both solutions into eternity, as, again, they're equally valid. If you already have a preference, go with it! :o)

Answer (score -2):

I will select the **first option** which seems to be better. If you use second options, the one with the GET, i am allowing users to tamper with my comment form which is bad and sometimes can create security issues if you do not pay attention to that.

Comment: A hidden field in the comment form can also be spoofed. "Security" is a non-issue as far as this decision goes.

Comment: Agree with Anon. Whatever you allow to be sent from the user's side, could actually be modified by the user.
that's the same reason DRM doesn't work so far...

Comment: @Anon: I said initially "I will select the first option which seems to be better." hidden approach is better than GET way but it is not perfect too, i never said that but because i was left with two optiosn i had to select one option. Hope you understand that.

Comment: You say it "seems to be better", but you did not provide *any* valid justification for that. If you're just pulling an opinion out of nowhere, say that you're pulling it out of nowhere instead of trying to justify it with something incorrect.